# Why are there two nested curly braces without any statement in-between?

Tags: c++, qt, syntax, moc

The code given below is the code generated by MOC in Qt.

> const QMetaObject
>   MainWindow::staticMetaObject = {
>       { &QMainWindow::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_MainWindow,
>         qt_meta_data_MainWindow, 0 } };

Why is there two continuous curly braces without anything statement in-between? Also, what does the statement mean? Just comma separated variable means anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is initializing a list (external braces) of structure (internal braces.)

Comment: it's more likely that it's a nested struct. since we don't see []'s and i don't suspect staticMetaObject is some array (though I could be wrong), the inner thing might be an array of pointers though.